# CakePHP 2.x How to determine view path in controller in beforeRender() or earlier?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

I have the need to determine what app path my controller method will use for serving up the view before it does so. I'm using a theme but I also have many non-themed view files. I'm switching my themes based on domain name (2 domains point to the same Cake install) but need to exclude the non-themed views from rendering inside my theme.

This may sound confusing. Here's what is currently happening if a URL is accessed that does not have a theme view associated with it:

> domainA.com/examples/index will render the view app/View/Examples/index.ctp with the layout from app/View/Layouts
>
> domainB.com/examples/index will render the view app/View/Examples/index.ctp BUT with the layout from app/View/Themed/MyTheme/Layouts

This is because the "MyTheme" theme does not contain a view file for this controller-method pair (this is intentional). So I would like to instead have the following established:

> domainB.com/examples/index continues to render the view app/View/Examples/index.ctp BUT INSTEAD with the layout from app/View/Layouts

This should only happen, of course, if and only if there is no view file within the "MyTheme" directory structure.

Comment: `This may sound confusing` - it does. So, you want to use your theme only if the requested view exists in the theme, otherwise you want to use no theme? That sounds like a view class with a method (templateExistsInTheme) based on [_getViewFileName](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.next/lib/Cake/View/View.php#L989-L1032).

Comment: Good to "see" you again @AD7six :-) That method looks like what I need but for some reason it's not giving me the path to the view within my theme, but rather the non-themed view path. I'm setting the controller's theme property to my custom theme prior to instantiating & calling the method you recommended, but still it returns only the "base" (non-themed) path. And to answer your question btw: I really would prefer to not render anything but redirect the user in the case you described.

Comment: :). Are you sure about that? theme paths are not handled in a special way (well they are, but you'll see what I mean), they are just [prefixed to the paths to look for a template file](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.next/lib/Cake/View/View.php#L1152-L1164) which [_getViewFilename](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.next/lib/Cake/View/View.php#L1022) is calling. If that method does not return the path to a theme view, either no theme was requested or the themed view file doesn't exist.

Comment: Debugging `$paths`and [here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.next/lib/Cake/View/View.php#L1026) will tell you which.

Comment: The reason I stated that is because _getViewFileName() is returning just that... the view file that it actually finds, but regardless of where it is within the filesystem. In my case, I need to filter on whether that view is within the theme directory path or the base (non-themed) path. So I ended up just writing my own check since it's only a very specialized edge case where I need this behavior. Thanks as always.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for `$this->View->viewPath`.

You can use this in any controller call back function or action.